# In MFC Close only the Child Dialog, not the Parent

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm a newcomer to MFC world. I need to have some dialog based operaion for an old application. There I'm having a trouble for an appraently obvious thing and that is I can't seem to find a way to close the child dialog (Modal) that I'm invoking from my parent (also a Modal). In all the ways I tried always both child and parent is getting closed at once.
Here is what I tried:
I've created a default MFC application in VS 2012 Professional
ParentDlg.cpp

```
void ParentDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{       
    ChildDlg childDlg;
    dialogOutput.DoModal(); 

    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

In my Child.cpp for a Close button (ID: IDCLOSE)
ChildDlg.cpp

```
void ChildDlg::OnBnClickedClose()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    EndDialog(IDCLOSE);
}
```

But this is closing both the parent and child, but I need only the child dialog to be closed (Parent Dialog should remain open) as I'm clicking the 'Close' buton on the child dialog.

In short, I like to have the same behaviour of the default IDOK button of 'IDD_ABOUTBOX' dialog, which is also a Modal dialog and closes only the About Box when I click on the 'OK' button in it.

Comment: 1) Is this real code? `dialogOutput` is undefined in `ParentDlg::OnBnClickedOk`. 2) If it is meant to be `childDlg` - why do you call `CDialogEx::OnOK` right after `DoModal` call, if you don't want to close the `ParentDlg` as well? It is explained in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/132s802t.aspx#cdialog__onok), that calling the base handler will close the dialog..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, that should have been ChildDlg, I corrected that in my post. And removing default CDialogEx::OnOK worked :) I was overlooking that as MFC was writing that line when I was creating the 'click' event there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should only place IDOK in the ID property of your close button. And only the child dialog will close. You should no longer create an event handler, and if you did, delete the event handler.

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem was in ParentDlg, in the button click event I kept the default CDialoxEx::OnOK() call, that was responsible for the parent  dialog to close as well. removing that line solved the issue.